# Why is the expected value of the mean-square of the treatments in Anova equal to the variance plus the sum of squares of the treatment effects?

Tags: anova, variance

We define the sum of squares of the treatments in Anova this way:

$SS(T)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{a}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i} (\bar{X}_{i.}-\bar{X}_{..})^2$

And the Mean-square(T) (MST) is simply equal to:

$\frac{SS(T)}{a - 1}$, where $a$ = number of treatments

However, the $\mathbb{E}[MS(T)] = \sigma^2 + \frac{n \sum_{i=1}^a \tau_i^2}{a - 1}$

I want to make sure I understand the intuition here.

The $\tau$'s are the treatment effects of a fixed effects model.

Because the expected value in one-way Anova is a consequence of the model ($ y_{i,j} = \mu+ \tau_i + \epsilon$) and we know the variance of $y_{i,j}$ in this model is $\sigma^2$ due to random error. Then are we ultimately saying that $\mathbb{E}[MS(T)]$ is composed of the random error from the model and the mean-square of the treatments themselves (assuming treatments are zero-centered)?

Thus, the expected value is biased by $\sigma^2$.

That makes sense to me but I wanted to confirm and gather a better understanding.